# Enabling a Menu item in the Main Menu in a SwiftUI macOS app?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I've created a Main Menu item for **File**, called **Refresh**, mapped CMD-R to it. But for some reason, the Main Menu item is disabled, when launching the app.

The settings are:
[image: Refresh Menu Item details]

But when I launch the app, the main menu shows the Refresh item as disabled. When I click on WKWebView view and press CMD-R, and then open the main menu, the Refresh item is enabled.

How do I make the Refresh item enabled by default?
[image: Disabled Refresh menu item]

EDIT: One very interesting detail: The minute I click on the WKWebView - the Refresh-item becomes active. So, should I have done this in a different way? I currently have it linked like this:

Refresh Menu Item linked to First Responder, with `reloadFromOrigin:` selected.

Comment: How do yo add a menu command to your SwiftUI app like that?

Comment: @DuncanC hi, i tried to explain with screenshots in the original post - i create the menu command by clicking on the Menu Item. i'm not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Menu items are validated by FirstResponder. When application just started the first responder in your case, seems main window and below by responder chain, does not have implemented selector of that menu item (probably, `reload(_:)`), so menu item is disabled.

When you click on WKWebView it becomes first responder and menu item becomes enabled, because it has implemented `reload(_:)` selector.

So you need to implement `reload(_:)` selector either in overridden root view controller or in AppDelegate and do in it what's needed.

Comment: I just had the presence of mind to edit the original question, since noticed that the Refresh menu item is automatically enabled in the main menu when clicking on WKWebView. And also added that I've mapped it to First Responder and then to reloadFromOrigin: :) now I gotta find where to place the stronger implementation, so that the Refresh menu item is always selected